# I need to take first 4 characters of first line in a file and i need it in a variable

Tags: shell-script, historical-unix

I have a file 
like

sample1.txt

```
ABCDE10998909
10898990XYZ
1898772222YGH
8980000000000sihgj
```

Output:

```
ABCD
```

I need to take first 4 characters of first line in a file and i need it in a variable.

Comment: You've tagged your question with [tag:historical-unix].  What Unix and shell are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Using `head` and `cut`:

```
$ variable=$( head -n 1 sample1.txt | cut -c 1-4 )
$ printf 'variable is %s\n' "$variable"
variable is ABCD
```

This extracts the first line using `head` and then cuts out the first four characters using `cut`.  Note that some implementations of `cut` may return the first four *bytes* rather than the first four *characters* (e.g. GNU `cut`). This would make a difference if the data is using multibyte characters.

Using `sed`:

```
$ variable=$( sed 's/^\(....\).*/\1/;q' sample1.txt )
$ printf 'variable is %s\n' "$variable"
variable is ABCD
```

This uses `sed` and substitutes the first line with its first four characters, and then simply exits `sed` after outputting the modified line.

Both these variants would produce fewer than four characters if the first line contained fewer than four characters.

Your question is tagged with [historical-unix](/questions/tagged/historical-unix).  In an older `sh` shell, you may want to use back-ticks (`` `...` ``) for command substitutions rather than the more modern (and saner) `$(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming historical UNIX by which I'm assuming `bash` or more recent shells are not supported, you can do it in a POSIX compliant way

```
if IFS= read -r line 2> /dev/null < file; then 
    result="${line%"${line#????}"}"
    printf '%s\n' "$result" 
else
    printf >&2 '%s\n' 'Unable to read file contents or no newline found in the file'
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

A GNU `grep` (or compatible) solution:

```
variable=$(grep -o -m1 '^....' file.txt)
```

where

- `-o` output match only
- `-m1` stop after one match
- `^` begin of line
- `....` any char, four times

note:

- `-o` is a non-standard GNU extension (though now supported by a few other implementations), that will report the first 4 characters of the first line that has at least 4.
- in other words, if the first line with 4 characters is the fifth one, this will report the first 4 characters of that line.

Answer (score 2):

If you use awk:

```
var=$(awk 'NR==1 {print substr($0, 1, 4)}' sample1.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since its mentioned you need to first 4 characters of first line need to be saved in a variable

```
command
variable=`awk 'NR==1{print substr($0,1,4)}' filename`
```

output

```
variable=`awk 'NR==1{print substr($0,1,4)}' filename`
echo $variable
ABCD
```

Answer (score 0):

Done by using python

```
praveen@praveen:~$ cat script.py 
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
import subprocess
m=re.compile(r'.{4}')
d=[]
h=open('l.txt','r')
for g in h:
    d.append(g.strip())
k=re.search(m,d[0])
print k.group()
praveen@praveen:~$
```

output

```
@praveen:~$ python script.py 
ABCD
```

Second method using python

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import re
    import subprocess
    m=re.compile(r'.{4}')
    d=[]
    h=open('l.txt','r')
    o=h.readline()
    l=re.search(m,o)
    print l.group().strip()

output

n@praveen:~$ python script.py 
ABCD
praveen@praveen
```